Problems setting up Qt for Clion
I am trying to set up Qt to work with Clion , but when I try and link the cmake configuration file from Qt , I get an error that tells me that the versions are not compatible .
Here is my cmake:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(Qt6_DIR "C:/Qt/6.5.5/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6")

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        CONFIG
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled
        Qt6::Core
)

if (WIN32 AND NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    set(DEBUG_SUFFIX)
    if (MSVC AND CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
        set(DEBUG_SUFFIX "d")
    endif ()
    set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
        set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        if (NOT EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin")
            set(QT_INSTALL_PATH "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/..")
        endif ()
    endif ()
    if (EXISTS "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/plugins/platforms/")
    endif ()
    foreach (QT_LIB Core)
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                "${QT_INSTALL_PATH}/bin/Qt6${QT_LIB}${DEBUG_SUFFIX}.dll"
                "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>")
    endforeach (QT_LIB)
endif ()

and this is the error I get:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Qt/6.5.5/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake, version: 6.5.5 (64bit)


I tried chnaging the minimum version of cmake required but i get the same thing

Those links might help, first GitHub project helped me on time
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html
https://github.com/kevinlyu/Clion-Qt5
https://github.com/KmolYuan/learn-qt
